# How to integrate Django server with Nodejs SocketIO server

Tags: node.js, django, socket.io

I'm finding a solution in integrate Client, Django and NodeJS. My task is building a server which user can **message** to each other. I have 2 solutions:

1. From Client send request to Django server. Django server will create Message in Database and push a notification to NodeJS server(SocketIO), then Client will get change from NodeJs server. With this solution, I want to ask **how can I push request socket from Django to Node?**

[image]

2. From Client send request to Socket server. Socket server will create Message in Database, then send it to Client. Is this solution good or bad? Does it need improvement?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using two server you will have to store socket_id against your user_id in the Database [Redis key value](https://redis.io/commands/set).

You will need :

- Django Api Server
- Redis or any other database
- Node Socket Server

**For second solution** **:**

Django API logic for sending message will have to be implemented on Node Socket server.

ex. user authentication, Checking target user, storing messages, finding user socket_id from database etc.

**For first solution** **:**

1. [Use Redis Pub-Sub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) :
   From Django Server you can publish message on an event ex "send_message"

> { event_name: "send_message", target_user_id:"t_id",
>   send_user_id:"u_id", target_socket_id:"t_sid", message:"Hello target"
>   }

On Node socket server you can Subscribe to that event and emit to specific socket_id

> `io.to(data.target_socket_id).emit("event", data);`

2. You can create an endpoint on node server to receive the data from django server and pass
   Body parameters

> { event_name: "send_message", target_user_id:"t_id",
>   send_user_id:"u_id", target_socket_id:"t_sid", message:"Hello target"
>   }

When node-server receives the API request you can use event emitter to emit the event

```
process.emit(data.event_name,data)
```

Inside Socket Connection File you can configure event listener

```
process.on("send_message",(data)=>{
    io.to(data.target_socket_id).emit("event", data); 
});
```

Comment: Do you think the first or the second solution is good and easy for management? Or something else? Why, bro?

Comment: @FeedGit I would prefer second solution for a simple chat application and use socket  acknowledgement [link](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements) and socket middle-ware [link](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn) for authentication when socket connects.It will keep all the logic at one place.Hence easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much Mukul. I'll try continuing with the Second.